# I want to get data from two different table in php with their id and special characters

Tags: php

```
$sqlr="SELECT * FROM category_add_data 
        WHERE brand_name = '$brandName'  AND id = '$brdid'";
```

The above sql is working fine with special character

```
<?php
    $reqrwqq="SELECT * FROM abdsdd 
                WHERE brand_name = '$brandName' AND category_name='$brandCate'
                ORDER BY id DESC";
?>
```

This is working fine until I insert a special character & also what if I have data from two differnt id.

Comment: have you tried inner Join?

Comment: yes, but not working.